# when i try to install apache-airflow have this error:Building wheel for google-re2

Tags: airflow

my phython is 3.7.4
I try to install apache-airflo on virtual environment see this error

Building wheel for google-re2 (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

x python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
?─> [9 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37
copying re2.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37
running build_ext
building '_re2' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for google-re2
Running setup.py clean for google-re2
Failed to build google-re2
ERROR: Could not build wheels for google-re2, which is required to install pypro
ject.toml-based projects

I trying on virtual environment